# Где должны юзаться enum'ы? Для чего их обычно используют?

Tags: c#, .net, enum

Вопрос возможно звучит глупо, но... Я немного не понимаю какова концепция enum, где их стоит применять, а где стоит воздержаться, из всего что я понял, это то что enum может хранить в себе последовательность констант. Но почему нельзя сделать просто коллекцию?

В общем, я в замешательстве. Буду благодарен любой помощи!

Comment: enum не хранит последовательность констант, а декларирует возможные значения поля. Т.е. само по себе объявление enum не занимает памяти, в отличие от коллекции.

Comment: enum можно юзать когда тебе необходимо декларировать какие-то "состояния" определенные (например TaskCompletionSource). Так же, enum помогает избавиться от [магических чисел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

Comment: Ну это же именованные константы. Которые можно потом использовать по именам. А не просто перечисление.

Comment: Близкий эквивалент -  просто статические классы с константами (как это делают в языках без enum). Но потом смотришь на сигнатуру метода, а оно вида `foo(int typeCode, int colorType, int flag)` и чешешь репу (читаешь доку если есть) в попытке разобраться, где именно лежит нужная константа, ведь `int` никак не говорит о диапазоне допустимых значений. А если вам этот `int` пришел извне уже как число и нужно передавать дальше, то компилятор вам не помощник. С enum же сразу понятно что надо и компилятор не даст напутать с параметрами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Любая коллекция, даже массив - это объект, под него требуется выделение памяти в рантайме. Что касается констант - они закладываются в момент компиляции и могут компилятором вшиваться даже в сам код.

Например.

```cs
const number = 42;
int i = number;
int j = number;
```

При компиляции преобразуется просто в

```
int i = 42;
int j = 42;
```

То есть, в литералы.

Совершенно то же самое с перечислением.

```cs
enum Number
{
    First = 42,
    Second = 123
}

Number i = Number.First;
Number j = Number.Second;
```

По умолчанию `Number` неявно наследует `int` и может быть явно преобразован в этот тип. Можете явно написать `enum Number : int`, и от этого совершенно ничего не поменяется.

Поэтому откомпилированный код логически будет выглядеть так

```cs
int i = 42;
int j = 123;
```

Конечно, есть еще рефлексия, аттрибуты и прочие примочки, позволяющие в консоль вывести значение перечисления как название константы, но когда само значение используется в коде, считайте, что это просто число.

Если интересно, а что за числа вот здесь

```cs
enum Value
{
    First, Second
}
```

То синтаксически, это эквивалент вот такой конструкции

```
enum Value : int
{
    First = 0,
    Second = 1
}
```

То есть опять везде числа, константы. Не даром вы не можете создать перечисление из строк.

Перечисления как коллекции - не существует в момент выполнения приложения. Перечисление в первую очередь позволяет вам удобно писать красивый, легкочитаемый код и меньше ошибаться.

Далее, есть случаи, когда нужно работать с флагами. Например, есть файл, его можно читать и писать

```cs
[Flags]
enum Permission
{
    None = 0,
    Read = 1,
    Write = 2,
    ReadWrite = Read | Write
}
```

А в коде легко проверить, какой флаг установлен, например, чтобы узнать, можно ли читать, достаточно написать

```cs
Permission access = Permission.ReadWrite;
if (access.HasFlag(Permission.Read))
{
    // ...
}
```

Без использования перечисления это выглядело бы вот так

```cs
int access = 3;
if ((access & 1) != 0)
{
    // ...
}
```

Согласитесь, код с использованием перечисления выглядит понятнее?

Конечно, это не полный список ситуаций, где перечисления использовать удобно, но основной смысл где-то в этом. Главное понять, что перечисление - это не коллекция как сущность, а просто некий набор констант.